# glReadPixels crash on iOS

Tags: ios, crash, glreadpixels

When the online user just opened the app, even now this collapses, and we can not reproduce ourselves. crash info:

```
libsystem_platform.dylib          0x183223b40 _sigtramp + 36 (sigtramp.c:109)
AGXMetalA10                       0x1a2ce15d8 
AGX::Texture<(AGXTextureMemoryLayout)1, AGX::G9::Encoders, 
AGX::G9::Classes>::readRegion(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 904 (agxa_texture_template.hpp:1038)
AGXMetalA10                       0x1a2ce15d8 
AGX::Texture<(AGXTextureMemoryLayout)1, AGX::G9::Encoders, 
AGX::G9::Classes>::readRegion(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 904    (agxa_texture_template.hpp:1038)
AGXMetalA10                       0x1a2ccaa7c    -[AGXA10FamilyTexture getBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:fromRegion:mipmapLevel:slice:] + 84 (agxa_texture_objc.mm:355)
AppleMetalGLRenderer              0x1a2d3e8a0    gldReadFramebufferData + 1260 (glr_framebuffer.mm:549)
GLEngine                          0x1a3a98074    glReadPixels_Exec + 1124 (gl_read_pixels.c:329)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dimension of your glReadPixel() call matters. For my case it seems that if I take an integer less than 32 as the height parameter, this crash happens. You might do a try and test.

Comment: Thank you. I will verify it.